# tshark stopping criteria

Tags: tshark

I need to stop tshark (command line equi of wireshark) after a certain condition is met.

From the tshark man pages, I found that stopping condition can be applied with respect to duration, files, file size and multiple files mode.

Is there any stopping condition I can apply through capture filter so that tshark stops capturing.

ex: Upon receiving a TCP SYN packet from a particular port number (condition applied in capture filter), tshark stops capturing.

Please answer this riddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output to head and pick the first frame that matches your query but you also need to disable output buffering (stdbuf is part of coreutils)

e.g (Linux)

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tshark -r file.pcap -Y 'sctp.verification_tag == 0x2552' | head -1
```

Mac:

```
gstdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tshark -r file.pcap  -Y 'tcp.flags.syn == 1 && tcp.port == 80' | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

When Wireshark 4.0.0 was released about 1 month ago, they changed how "-a" behaves in comparison to how "-c" behaves, and now "-a packets:1" does exactly what you want (5 years after your original question ).

From their [documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html#:~:text=This%20does%20not%20include%20any%20packets%20that%20do%20not%20pass%20the%20display%20filter):

> ###### -a|--autostop
>
> Specify a criterion that specifies when TShark is to stop writing to a capture file. The criterion is of the form test:value, where test is one of:
> - *duration:value* ...
> - *files:value* ...
> - *filesize:value* ...
> - *packets:value* switch to the next file after it contains value packets. **This does not include any packets that do not pass the display filter**, so it may differ from -c.

Although this fix was done ~8 months ago (see their [commit](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/commit/fc3f061829aa4ba20589bd4caa802aee1756f083)), it seems that they intended it for the 4.0 branch only, since non of the 3.6 branch have received this fix (including version 3.6.10 which is still being developed).